# Is there a better way to output cpu usage than ps?

Tags: monitoring, cpu-usage, ps

I want to write a command to output a list of the ten most cpu intensive processes running, as well as their cpu usage. I want to configure polybar to send me a notification with this data. Currently, the command I'm using is `notify-send CPU "$(ps axch -o cmd\:35,%cpu --sort=-%cpu | head)"`.

However, ps uses some weird method to calculate CPU usage so it doesnt add up to hundred and often exceeds hundred. Also, it gives the cpu usage over the entire life of the process and not its instantaneous usage. Is there a better way to get what I want?

Comment: Have you tried htop?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/522922/cpu-more-than-100-in-ps-aux